# Using jQuery to display each content of a button when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am working on practice work to improve myself 
I created a sidebar using jquery. Inside my sidebars I have 3 buttons.
Am trying to do something like when I click on the first button I want it to show me the contents inside the first button clicked

```
<div>
  <li Id = ‘list-1’ class = ‘btn btn-outline-success’> </li>
  <li Id = ‘list-2’ class = ‘btn btn-outline-success’> </li>
  <li Id = ‘list-3’ class = ‘btn btn-outline-success’> </li>
</div>
```

I want each button to display its contents

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: First, about your HTML markup... **Use an editor! (of your choice)** It will help you writing it correctly. These cute quotes `‘` `’` aren't valid. `Id` should be `id` (no capital)... Then, your JS code attempt is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Simple version (seeing as your code doesn't offer much direction)

```
 <div>
   <button id= "list-1" class="click-button btn btn-outline-success" value="Bicycle 1">Button</button>
   <button id="list-2" class="click-button btn btn-outline-success" value="Bicycle 2">Button</button>
   <button id="list-3" class="click-button btn btn-outline-success" value="Bicycle 3">Button</button>
 </div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '.click-button', function () {
   alert(this.value)
  })
 })
</script>
```